# slider with ajax content - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

i need a slider plugin, that load externals html's.

For example, four htmls correspond to 4 slides

Something like this: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most of the slider plugins can do this, even this Coda-Slider you used as example. In [this page](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/) there are some examples and there's one which can even show a youtube video. Through jQuery you could select the panel in which you want to load the html page and use `.load("page.html")`.

Generate a slider with four panels and load one html in each one of them.

```
$("#panel1").load("page1.html");
$("#panel2").load("page2.html");
$("#panel3").load("page3.html");
$("#panel4").load("page4.html");
```

I guess this works.

Comment: you are correct. Thanks. I discover same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068137/how-can-i-add-ajax-loading-to-niall-dohertys-coda-slider